# Как сделать сервис неубиваемым и без нотификации?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification, background-task

Здравствуйте. Мне нужен сервис, который всегда будет работать. Даже, когда пользователь будет удалять основное активити из таска. То есть сервис, который работает вообще всегда.
На данный момент мне частично удалось это сделать. Например: в версии Андроида 4.1.1 все работает отлично. Как видно на скриншотах нотификации отключены, из таска приложение удалено пользователем но мой service textAp работает и система его не убивает.

Android 4.1.1

[image] [image]

Но Android 4.4.x KitKat и версии выше, так хорошо уже себя не ведут, система начинает убивать мой сервис при удалении приложения из таска и единственный способ, который я нашел это добавить в сервис нотификацию и только после этого андроид позволил сервису жить дальше. Об этом написано и в официальной документации Google https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html , что для "неубиваемого" сервиса теперь нужно выводить уведомление в строку состояние. По таким соображениям, что пользователь должен видеть процессы, которые работают на фоне в его устройстве.

Android 4.4.4 KitKat

[image] [image]

Вроде все понятно. Разобрались. Андроид заботится о безопасности своих пользователей таким образом. Нельзя запустить сервис без этого назойливого уведомления вверху экрана. Ну и ладно, если так, значит так надо.

Но потом я увидел, что есть масса сторонних приложений, которые спокойно во всех версиях андроида запускают свои сервисы без всяких нотификаций и уведомлений.

Например WhatsApp или Wi-Fi Mouse

[image] [image]

Сервисы этих приложения, в отличии от моего, работают прекрасно без уведомления. Вот у меня и вопрос. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной ситуацией на практике? И удавалось запустить в последних версиях андроида "неубиваемый" сервис, который не отображает нотификацию в панели уведомлений. Или подскажите в какую сторону нужно примерно смотреть, чтоб получить такой результат.

---

Я частично нашел ответ на этот вопрос. Но еще сам до конца не разобрался. https://fossdroid.com/a/conversations.html  . Вот на этом сайте можно скачать исходный код месенджера в котором сервис работает так , как надо. Работает без всяких нотификаций и тд. Просто в фоне работает и система его не трогает. Если хорошо покопаться в коде этого месенджера, то можно найти как это сделано) И кстати это хороший сайт. В нем очень много профессиональных приложений с открытым кодом.